# ScrollTo particular item of ListiVew in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to scrollTo a particular item in listview in ionic 2. I have a listview which is bound to array.

```
export class TestPage {
    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
    public items: Array<Object> = [];

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        console.log(this.navParams.data);
        this.customService.getArray(this.params.index).then((items) => {
            this.items = items;
                //scroll to item
                // this.content.scrollTo()
        });
     }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="items" approxItemHeight="120px" approxItemWidth="100%" 
    class="items-listview list list-md">
  <button class="items-listview-item item item-md" *virtualItem="let item">
    <div class="items-listview-text">
        {{ item.text }}<span>{{item.index}}</span>
    </div>
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

I see that [scrollTo](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/#scrollToTop) only support position i.e top and left but not the element itself. How can i scrollTo listview item **(e. item no 150)** itself ? How can i get the position of **item no 150** and pass it to scrollTo?

Comment: I don't know if you solved this. At the moment when I'm looking at the docs there is no "scrollToItem", though you can calculate the position using your approxItemHeight and the index of the item and use `ionContent.scrollTo(0, approxItemHeight*index);` If you have headers or footers don't forget to calculate their height as well, and add that to your calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting the solution i come up with. First you need to give unique id to each listview item and then select the `ListView`

```
@ViewChild(VirtualScroll) listView: VirtualScroll;
```

After that i created a function (following) `ScrollTo` which has a timeout of resizing the listview after scrolling too (as i was changing buffer ratio dynamically).

```
private scrollTo(index: number) {
    let key = '#customIds_' + index;

    let hElement: HTMLElement = this.content._elementRef.nativeElement;
    let element = hElement.querySelector(key);
    element.scrollIntoView();

    //wait till scroll animation completes
    setTimeout(() => {
        //resize it! otherwise will not update the bufferRatio
        this.listView.resize();
    },500);
}
```

Last i just called this function after a second delay as i waited till listview loads:

```
//must be delay otherwise content scroll doesn't go to element properly..magic!
setTimeout(() => {
    this.scrollTo('someId');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can assign an id to each item (by doing something like `[id]="'item' + item.index"` and then in your code just use that id to get the `offsetTop`:

```
scrollTo(elementId:string) {
    let yOffset = document.getElementById(elementId).offsetTop;
    this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset, 4000)
}
```

Comment: but i need to scroll as soon as ionViewWillEnter fires. I am not currently in view

Comment: You can use `ionViewDidLoad` to make sure the content is already loaded, and get the `offsetTop` like it's being done in the code above. So instead of creating a new method, just put that code inside the `ionViewDidLoad` lifecycle event.

Comment: as you can see in my view i am using `[virtualScroll]` in which all items aren't visible. So this doesnt work if an item can't be seen

Comment: this answer worked perfectly for `ion-list` since all items in list was loaded

Comment: @VivekSinha no, you have to play around. this was just a starter for me.

Comment: @VivekSinha check my answer below. just in case your are still struggling with it..

Answer (score 4):

The current accepted answer only scrolled relative to the parent element, so here is what I came up with to scroll to the selected element (without traversing the DOM).

```
  scrollTo(element:string) {
    let elem = document.getElementById(element);
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

    var body = document.body;
    var docEl = document.documentElement;

    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
    var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
    var top  = box.top +  scrollTop - clientTop;
    var cDim = this.content.getContentDimensions();

    var scrollOffset = Math.round(top) + cDim.scrollTop - cDim.contentTop;

    this.content.scrollTo(0, scrollOffset, 500);
  }
```

Comment: thanks, it's working, only there was some minor position calculation error if the page got a header, in my case.