# Ioinc 2/Angular 2 - How do I scrollToBottom a div?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to autoScroll a particular div to bottom whenever a new message is received. The solutions that I found only mentioned scroll for the `content` element.

```
<ion-content class="page mc-page">

    <div class="chatpanel">

        <!--I want to auto scroll .chattxt-w -->
        <div class="chattxt-w" #chattxt>

            <!--load all messages-->
            <div class="wtxt s3 msgitem" text-left *ngFor="let msgs of messages">{{msgs.msg}}</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Isn't this your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339158/scrollto-particular-item-of-listivew-in-ionic-2

Comment: Not exactly, He used  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content; whereas I don't want to access ion-content , I just want to access #chattxt and then scroll only that div's scrollarea to the bottom

Comment: You want to scroll the div with the class .chatpanel?

Comment: @LlorençPujolFerriol No, I want to scroll the contents of .chattxt-w

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ViewChild, and do an scroll bottom every time a new message is recived. You can do like so:

```
@Component(...)
export class YourComponent {
    ViewChild('chattxt') chattxt: ElementRef;

    onMessageRevieved(){
      this.chattxt.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.chattxt.nativeElement.scrollHeight
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did try this. But I got an error saying - scrollHeight undefined

Comment: Yeah, sorry, if you are using nativeScrolling this would not work, is not a proper solution with Ionic. Maybe you could give a try to the component <ion-scroll> that would wrap both native and none native scroll

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content>
```

Add your content here!

```
</ion-content>

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{


@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;


scrollToTop() {
this.content.scrollToTop();


 }}
```

i think this will help